# Notify the controller of a button clicked in view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

How do I notify the controller that the delete button was clicked?

MyController.php

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    isset($_POST['del'])
    {
       // delete user.
    }
}
```

MyView.php

```
<?php
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="deleteButton">Delete User</button>'; 
?>
```

This is what I tried:

```
    $('.deleteButton').click(function()
    {
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = Yii::app()->basePath . '/controllers/MyController.php';

        del =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
        $.post(ajaxurl, del, function (response) 
        {

            alert("action performed successfully");
        });
    });
```

But I can't receive the notice on the controller that the button was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

1. It seems you use jQuery. `$('.deleteButton')` selects element by class, not by name. `$('[name="deleteButton"]')` should be used instead.
2. You can't inject PHP code in JS this way. If your JS is written in a view, you should wrap the PHP code `<?=Yii::app()->basePath ?>`.
3. Yii uses URL manager. It means URL does not equal controller file path. Build a URL from view `<?=$this->createUrl('my/update', array('id' => $userId) ?>`. Lear more about [url management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager).